# Identification of a space with a subset of the topological cone

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

> Let $X$ be a topological space and define the cone $c(X)= (X \times I)/(X \times \{1\})$. Identify $X$ with $\{\{(x,0)\} \mid x \in X\} \subset c(X)$. Show that a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ is null-homotopic if and only if it has a continuous extension $g:c(X)\to Y$.

I might have missed a part in lectures on quotient spaces, but what do they mean by "identifying" $X$ with the set $\{\{(x,0)\} \mid x \in X\}$? Do they want me to treat the points of $X$ as the elements $\{(x,0)\}$? If so what is the purpose of this identification?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do much. As you said, treat points in $X$ as points in $c(X)$, specifically by regarding each $x \in X$ as $\{(x, 0)\} \in c(X)$.

Why the set brackets? Remember, $c(X)$ is a quotient of $X \times I = X \times [0, 1]$, identifying all the points of the form $(x, 1)$ together. This means $c(X)$ will consist of equivalence classes of points, where $X \times \{1\}$ is one equivalence class, making all points of the form $(x, 1)$ equivalent, and every other point $(x, t)$, where $0 \le t < 1$, forms its own equivalence class $\{(x, t)\}$.

Why do we do this identification? It makes things nicer. It also is necessary for the question to make sense. It talks about $f : X \to Y$ having a continuous extension $g : c(X) \to Y$. This only makes sense if $X$ is a subset of $c(X)$, which it is not, strictly speaking. By pretending that $\{(x, 0)\} \in c(X)$ and $x \in X$ are the same point, then $X$ becomes, in our eyes, a subset of $X$, so the idea of extending it to the rest of $c(X)$ makes sense.